# Calling web services from your JSF code

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, jsf

Let's say that you have a presentation tier in JSF, and that your business tier is accessed using web services. How would you call your web services from JSF?

I was considering to have my backing beans to call the web services, but I just though I could use Ajax with JSF in order to connect to the web services. What would you choose and why? Any other choice you could recommend?

**EDIT:** I'm using Spring in the business tier, maybe that info may help with the suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd wrap the web service call in a service class, that is accessed via the managed bean. Thus the front-end will not know how exactly the data comes to it - via web services, or via any other means.

Comment: +1 I agree with Bozho - I like to keep the web service calls in service class & keep the presentation layer isolated from any web service changes that happen in the future.

Comment: Thanks again Bozho, I'm taking this approach.

Answer (score 3):

> Let's say that you have a presentation tier in JSF, and that your business tier is accessed using web services. How would you call your web services from JSF?

The "classic" approach would be to inject a JAX-WS proxy factory class (generated from the WSDL) in a ManagedBean:

```
public class ItemController {
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/CatalogService/Catalog?wsdl")
    private CatalogService service;

    public DataModel getItems() {
        if (model==null  || index != firstItem){
            model=getNextItems();
        }
        return this.model;
    }
    public DataModel getNextItems() {
        Catalog port = service.getCatalogPort();
        model = new ListDataModel(port.getItems( firstItem,batchSize));
        return model;
    }
}
```

Sample taken from [Sample Application using JAX-WS, JSF, EJB 3.0, and Java](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2007/09/sample_applicat_2.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would implement EJBs and expose them as web service (for language independet remote access) within the application I would access the EJBs by lookup and direct call them (for better performance). Unfortunatly you did not tell what platform you're using, so I can't be sure whether my suggestions would be feasible.

Comment: I'm using Spring in the business tier.